# Why does `openssl asnparse` not give an error but `openssl x509` does for a DER file?

Tags: openssl, x509, asn.1, pkcs#7, der

I have a base64 encoded file (named `bst`) that after base 64 decoding (`base64 -d bst > bst.der`) becomes a DER encoded file (`bst.der`). Running the command `openssl asn1parse -inform der -in bst.der` does not give errors and displays it. But running the command `openssl x509 -inform der -in bst.der` gives the below error when I thought it was supposed to display the file in a more human readable format? It also gives an error when running with `openssl pkcs7` and `openssl pkcs8`.

`Could not read certificate from bst.der 40F7679CD07F0000:error:1608010C:STORE routines:ossl_store_handle_load_result:unsupported:../crypto/store/store_result.c:151: Unable to load certificate`

If the file is a valid ASN.1 file, why can it not be read as another format?

Comment: How do you know your input data is a valid X509 certificate?  There are an infinite number of sets of valid ASN.1 data sets that aren't valid X509 certificates.

Comment: `openssl x509` only reads certificates, `openssl pkcs7` reads PKCS7/CMS blobs, etc... you'd need the command that corresponds to whatever the data format it.  It's like saying "xxd can print it as hex, but [game] won't load it as a savefile..."

Comment: I'm using SoapUI to generate a SOAP request, and the file `bst` is the text from a tag which is base64 encoding some version of a client side certificate. I'm trying to understand what SoapUI is creating. Would it help if I dumped the contents of `asn1parse` into the question?

Comment: This is an offshoot of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77609291/does-anyone-know-how-to-generate-a-valuetype-of-x509pkipathv1-in-the-binarysecur. It's possible this question is superfluous, but I wasn't sure if ASN1 was in effect almost always a certificate like PEM is almost always a certificate.

Comment: Just adding for context. But another reason I conflated ASN1 and DER is https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_ASN1

Comment: Answered at #77609291 -- your data is (DER) _SEQUENCE OF_ Certificate which is not the same as Certificate